# GIMP Change pixel to transparent only if above/below layer color match

Tags: gimp

I have an image - game map. It was generated a long time ago and not by me.
I wan to reverse-engeneer this map to create my own tileset.
E.g. I have a tile with `grass with tree`:
[image: grass with tree]
And I have a tile with `grass` only:
[image: grass]

I want with GIMP to detect only difference between each pixel. If they match - make them transparent. So that I can get `tree` tile. So the desired result should be like this `three without grass`:
[image: three without grass]

How can I do this with GIMP?

This works but with wiered effects: Copy `grass` -> paste into new layer on top of `three with grass` -> apply blend mode for grass layer as `color erase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to distinguish the green "native" to the tree and the green from the grass so `Color erase` is going to make things a bit transparent all over.

Possible technique:

1. Put the top layer in "Difference" mode.
2. In the Channels list, drag the Green channel to the general area to make a copy of it
3. Make a copy of the three+grass
4. Add a layer mask, initialize to the copied channel
5. `Color > Invert` the mask
6. Threshold the mask (very low value)

[image]

If needed you can paint the mask to restore pixels.

(the layer group isn't absolutely necessary, it is only used to show what the Difference looks like)

Edit: a slighty simpler/faster workflow is to replace steps 2 & 4 by:

- In 2., right-click the Green channel and `Channel to selection`
- In 4., initialize the mask with the selection.

Also, make sure that you aren't de-selecting the Green channel in the process (which is what happened in the screenshot above). You may have to explicitly re-select it.

Comment: Thanks for reply!
1) what layer should be on top? `grass` or `tree+grass` ?
3) how to copy? right click on `tree+grass` layer and `Duplicate Layer` ?
4) `Layer` -> `Mask` -> `Add Layer Mask` ? What "initialize to the copied channel" means ?
6) `Colors` -> `Threshold` ?

Comment: 1) Any, "Difference" mode is commutative 3) yes, or the middle icon at the bottom of the Layers list 4) Yes, and the dialog has an "Initialize layer mask" question 6) Yes